# Can inputs and outputs of hadoop be other than files?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

i am trying to write a hadoop mapreduce program in java. For which the input is an array and output is also an array. But till now i have only seen people use inputs and outputs as files for it. So i was just wondering if mapreduce can have any other input and output formats.

Thanks

Comment: ??? Files are effectively arbitrary arrays of binary data. What else are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

A wide variety of the Input and Output formats are supported by Hadoop. Check the subclasses of [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) and [OutputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/OutputFormat.html). Extend the InputFormat and OutputFormat if any custom formats are required. Check this [article](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/database-access-with-hadoop/) from Cloudera on DB input/output format.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is a file system and the point of map-reduce is to tackle large amount of data that would usually not fit in memory - so input and output would usually be stored on disks somehow (a.k.a. files).
Hadoop mapreduce classes comes with support for reading the different types of files supported by hadoop (text files, sequential files) you can also write your own sources e.g. [HBase comes with a map-reduce wrappe](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/MapReduce)r that reads its format of file. I haven't tried that but you can, as the article pointed by Praveen demonstrate, read from other sources

Output is even easier - since you're writing Java code you can do whatever in your reduce phase, so if you want to, say, put messages into a queue in the reduce  phase just do that